# ClickOnce signing - what is actually signed?

Tags: c#, clickonce

When a ClickOnce application is published/deployed, what exactly happens in the signing process? Is it just the manifest files that are signed? Or do all of the dlls generated from the build need to be signed? Or both?

Answer (score 2):

**Both the application (executable) and the manifest need to be signed.** What gets signed during publish will depend on your configuration.

If you check the "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" checkbox in Visual Studio, only the manifest will get signed, but not the application exe.

Because the manifest includes the signature of the exe, you want to sign the exe first, then the manifest. This will ensure the manifest includes the signed exe. To get both the manifest and executable signed in the correct order, there is a very good blog post http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/windows-8-and-clickonce-the-definitive-answer-2/